# Отобразить picturebox в usercontrol

Tags: c#, winforms, usercontrol, picturebox

PictureBox формируется в основной форме, а затем через foreach я вызываю новый usercontrol в который добавляю picturebox и текст для label. Label заполняется, а картинка пустая. Так же в основной форме у меня на pb подписываются события. Мне нужно передать picturebox в usercontrol со всеми подписками.

Класс с picturebox и названиями.

```
public class UserCtr
{
    public event Action<List<Users>> ClickPicture;
    public event Action<List<Users>, Group> DoubleClickPicture;
    public Group group { get; set; }
    public PictureBox picture { get; set; }
    public List<Users> users { get; set; }

    public UserCtr(Group group, PictureBox picture, List<Users> users)
    {
        this.group = group;
        this.picture = picture;
        this.users = users;
        this.picture.Click += PictureClick;
        this.picture.MouseDoubleClick += PictureDoubleClick;
    }
    private void PictureClick(object s, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClickPicture(users);
    }
    private void PictureDoubleClick(object s, EventArgs e)
    {
        DoubleClickPicture(users, group);
    }

}
```

Цикл по которому я вызываю новый usercontrol

```
foreach (var item in groups.users)
    {
        item.picture.Image = yellow;
        panel.Controls.Add(new UserControl1(item.picture)
        {
            Text = item.user.Name,
            //pb = item.picture
    });
    }
```

И сам usercontrol

```
  public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1(PictureBox pic)
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        Load += (s, e) => pictureBox1 = pic;
        Invalidate();
    }
    protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnTextChanged(e);
        label1.Text = Text;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Да, winforms...

Comment: А зачем передавать picturebox, если можно просто передать содержимое(bitmap), а pb создать новый прямо в UserControl ? У вас типичное мышление начинающего, который не отделяет данные программы от контролов UI, которые должны только отображать эти данные или считывать пользовательский ввод новых данных. Котлеты от мух надо бы отделять.

Comment: Контрол нужно добавить на родительский, чтобы он начал отображаться. Присвоение: `pictureBox1 = pic;` не делает этого. Используйте дополнительно `pictureBox1.Parent = this;` или `this.Controls.Add(pictureBox1);`

Comment: После чего старый контрол (пикчабокс) станет осиротевшим и его нужно бы задиспозить... Поэтому прислушайтесь к совету Bulson'а.

Comment: А я смотрю, у меня Parent null... Я уж и IContainerControl реализовал....